# My ggplot works without shiny, but when I use shiny it does not render without any error

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, graph, shiny

I've been trying to get a graph to plot in shiny, but I've ran into a wall since I get no errors, but my ggplot is not showing.
A little background information: It's a graph displaying how many games you would need in League of Legends to go from P4 to D4. It takes 400 points and players earn a different amount of points depending on how close their hidden rating is compared to what is show. Some people get +15 for a win and -15 for a loss, but others get +20 for a win and -10 for a loss (meaning that the system wants their shown rating to increase faster since they play better.

Basically I've made a simulation for 1000 players, how many games it would take at different winrates, so a simple binomial probability (flipping a weighted coin).

I don't think we need to worry much about the simulation/ggplot part, as they run perfectly well without shiny.

I just want to make it into a shiny app so that people can select their LP gains and LP losses from a slider.

I'll post the code below so you can have a look.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Enter LP gains and Losses"),
  
  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput(inputId = "LPgain",
                  label = "LP gain:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30),
      sliderInput(inputId = "LPloss",
                  label = "LP loss:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plt")
      
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  results <- reactive({
    
    winrates = c(51:70)/100
    frame = data.frame()
    
    for (i in winrates){
      Gamesi = c()
      for (y in 1:1000){
        LP = 0
        Games = 0
        while (LP < 400){
          Games = Games + 1
          vic = rbinom(1,1, i)
          if (vic == 1){LP = LP + input$LPgain}
          else {LP = LP - input$LPloss}
          if (LP < 0){LP = 0}
        }
        Gamesi = append(Gamesi, Games + 3)
      }
      wr = paste("per", i * 100, sep = "")
      Gamesi = data.frame(group = wr, value = Gamesi)
      assign(wr, Gamesi)
    }
    plot.data = rbind(per51, per52, per53, per54, per55, per56, per57, per58, per59, per60, per61, per62, per63, per64, per65, per66, per67, per68, per69, per70)
    return(plot.data)
  })
  
  means <- reactive({
    means <- aggregate(value ~  group, results(), mean)
    means$value = round(means$value)
    return(means)
  })
  
  output$plt <- renderPlot({
  
    p = ggplot(results(), aes(x=group, y=value)) +
      geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=NA) +
      scale_x_discrete(labels=c(51:70)) +
      ylim(0,1500) +
      geom_text(data = means(), aes(label = value, y = 1500)) + 
      xlab("Winrate (in %)") + 
      ylab("Number of games needed") +
      ggtitle(paste("A thousand people climbing from P4 to D4 (", LPgain, " LP win & ", LPloss, "LP loss)")) + 
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
    print(p)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I think we do need to worry about the simulation part.  It's hideously inefficient and is an almost infinite loop.  Try it with `y in 1:10` and `LP < 40` and the response is almost instant.  I think this is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: Thank you for your response. You are right. However, if I do a simulation with only 10 people, results varry to much to make any conclusions.

Comment: I agree.  So the solution is to rewite the simulation part to make it more efficient: the reason your plot doesn't appear is that it takes *a very long time* for the `results` reactive to compute.  That means you have a choice: either keep it as it is and wait, or rewrite it to be more efficient.  One idea: as a general rule, if you use a loop in R, there's probably a better way to do it.  Voting to close because the question does not address the real problem.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as discussed in comments, the problem is not with Shiny but with the method of simulation.